# Ожидание ввода текста без остановки программы

Tags: c#, winforms

В моей программе есть вкладка, где я могу написать и запустить код. При его запуске, появляется окошко с двумя TextBox'ами, в первом вывод, а во втором ввод информации.
Для ввода информации, мне нужно сделать свои методы Read и ReadLine. Но столкнулся с проблемой, так как не знаю, как ожидать ввод информации в TextBox, без остановки всей программы.
Вот мой код:

```cs
namespace PipeConsole {
    public partial class Form3 : Form {
        public static bool WaitingForRead { get; set; }
        public static string Input { get; set; }
        public static CompilerResults Results { get; set; }

        public Form3 (string source) {
            InitializeComponent ();
            CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider ();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters ();
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add (typeof (MethodsForConsolePipe.Chat).Assembly.Location);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            Results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource (parameters, source);
            Results.CompiledAssembly.GetType ("ConsolePipe").InvokeMember ("Main", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, null); 
        }
        //Компилируется и запускается код из консоли

        private void KeyPressed (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !e.Shift && WaitingForRead) {
                WaitingForRead = false;
                Input = (sender as TextBox).Text;
            }
        } 
        //Обработка нажатия клавиш в textBox
    }

    public class Console {
        public static string ReadLine () {
            Form3.WaitingForRead = true;
            //Тут должен ожидаться ввод
            return Form3.Input;
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне кажется, так как KeyPressed и Console.ReadLine у меня в одном потоке, а нужно что бы они работали синхронно, то нужно что-то сделать именно с потоками или пулом потоков. Но мне ничего в голову не пришло. Надеюсь Вы поможете. Заранее спасибо!

Вот обработка ввода:

```cs
       private void KeyPressed (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !e.Shift && WaitingForRead) {
                WaitingForRead = false;
                Input = textBox1.Text;
            }


    public class ConsoleP {
        public static string ReadLine () {
            Form3.WaitingForRead = true;
            while (Form3.WaitingForRead)
                Thread.Sleep (5);
            return Form3.Input;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А чем не устраивают штатные события TextBox-а?

Comment: Как с их помощью я могу реализовать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: Вроде разобрался сам. Создал второй поток, в котором работает код из консоли, а в первом обрабатываю нажатия. Но интересно, есть ли более красивое решение?

Comment: Стоп, какая еще консоль? Вы консольные команды через свое приложение запускаете? тогда все еще проще - перенаправляете потоки ввода вывода консольного приложения или самой оболочки (cmd/power shell) в свое приложение, пишете в поток ввода из одного TextBox, читаете поток вывода в другой. А вообще, опишите задачу, которую решаете, вместе с комментариями вопрос становится все менее понятным.

Comment: Совсем забыл сказать, консоль - это просто TextBox. В него я ввожу код, а потом компилирую его через CodeProvider.  При компиляции и его запуске, открывается окошко с двумя TextBox, в верхнем вывод, в нижнем ввод. Дальше я сделал свои методы ConsoleP.ReadLine, Read, Write, WriteLine. Но была проблема с Read, ReadLine, так как я не знал, как приостановить динамически скомпилированный код и ждать ввода. В итоге придумал запускать код во 2 потоке, а обрабатывать нажатия в 1. Не знаю, есть ли лучше способ.

Comment: Ок, то что вы разделили потоки скомпилированного динамического кода и UI  это правильно. Осталось научить скомпилированный код читать данные из входного потока и писать их в выходной. При этом если во входном потоке данных нет - ждать пока они там появятся. Сами потоки можно организовать на MemoryStream-ах

Comment: Я мало работал с потоками, так что не знаю, как их тут использовать. В вопрос добавил мою реализацию ввода.

Comment: Попробую набросать рабочий  пример, но пока ни чего не могу сказать по времени, как-то много всего накопилось